# domain Key - where to put the private key?

Tags: key, private, domainkeys

OK - so i've created a domain key for my domain and added all the required NDS settings.

But i can't seem to find a straight answer about where to put the private key?!

I'm using plesk 11.

instructions frm the generator are -

> Selector  cmkey1 Private Key
>   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIICXQIBAAKBgQDLuyX2W+17FnPK5aO2cxyVNF5SESXv9K6y1UVkcFDrMmhba7cX
>   eZ8akzB6I61Dc58vdo8PHMqw5Cxfd4yH8EYu2gyWtqXNPurl0OKorgGmGYpeiV96
>   JLUcVy4o7B6VKHktMgMTIaxE1pzSwC2VQil/hsbXVAKv2kO3x/QYnf2ODwIDAQAB
>   AoGBAJOEeaJ/Qd/kjAeYbAiKJWIsPzexTwUG6RB4uPxXD2CeaU35GuQWnowBlBJ8
>   jtLOf69Aa6oHsQSQ00h1Kf6sjkPHo826XOWwDOfvJhIoX8qC1fg6TFh0qgpiGxFt
>   1gjBgcltsgvNmH45n+OmFiV0MyvLhLwcZpqdT8z6AAC10rqhAkEA6zzL3An6ulxq
>   gdzB/bwphlqP746ly5rRWwmWLZ2+FbFb7lKPtD5W7YfdKN7UEAZmB0hm6sIt+XWd
>   zeIqgGMfiQJBAN22dlm52VTixL2zXbF1YwLw0tbyA3tCXq+CPQzFv7H5o0hlghow
>   CBL5+p55D/ek+LoWl9neKtRqp3AL+znHAtcCQCsFuXsK0DJZSJlrmIchbK7HzV9Q
>   xX3RWMy/mhnJqcQp5dhWfTXH2PokSQx6hGpR4UMfuMLitKnVGwFWhdNpTZECQQCY
>   OOJhEFzLDzcNF81IPdRQ/I+FzHvfcN4Zmk3YKx1GUKNu3WLKIBgrDz6m92+jE71B
>   5qkziHnXhbKYF2HRdXXZAkAThOzGq3bWNt2ebT6sEW+IJ4+8NH689Hc3E4F6fvEN
>   LRFiCUIlYRYobvxMfVq4KiTFiieA0Mj6VnKq2OaiIRkW
>   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
>
> Setting up your DNS You will need to create two text records to your
>   DNS server with the following information:
>
> Name  Value
>   _domainkey.jynk.net   t=y;o=~; cmkey1._domainkey.jynk.net k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDLuyX2W+17FnPK5aO2cxyVNF5S
>   ESXv9K6y1UVkcFDrMmhba7cXeZ8akzB6I61Dc58vdo8PHMqw5Cxfd4yH8EYu2gyW
>   tqXNPurl0OKorgGmGYpeiV96JLUcVy4o7B6VKHktMgMTIaxE1pzSwC2VQil/hsbX
>   VAKv2kO3x/QYnf2ODwIDAQAB

I'm presuming i need to add the PRIVATE KEY to some file via shh?!

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - so it turns out when you activate domain keys via plesk the PRIVATE KEY is created somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

One thing, a "private" key is supposed to be PRIVATE! Not shared on the internet. Before anything, you will now need to get yourself a new private key.